# Buying goods online from Canada to EU is VAT free?

Tags: canada, eu, import-taxes, taxes, vat

I read that Canada and EU now have a free trade agreement. Does this mean that as a private person, if I order some goods online, like a laptop, or a TV, or anything will be VAT free if it comes to the EU?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about travel.

Comment: It is about travelling of goods :D but it is just as applicable if you are the courier yourself and taking home stuff from Canada or the EU...

Comment: Fyi VAT applies to goods made and bought within the EU including within a single country, so there's no reason it wouldn't apply to imports/exports.

Comment: FWIW, even travelling within the EU sometimes you have to pay VAT - not all of the EU is in the EU VAT Area...

Comment: You’ve been confused by the term “free trade agreement”, which is highly misleading. Such agreements do not allow trade in goods, labour, capital and services between countries as freely as within countries — in truth, they are only trade agreements, allowing tariff- and quota-free trade in many (but generally not all) goods. The only real international free trade area is the European Economic Area (which still has many restrictions on trade between its members, but few enough that it can be considered to be free trade).

Comment: "if you are the courier yourself and taking home stuff from Canada or the EU" - that's very different from the actual question: "if I order some goods online..."

Comment: Afaict the main difference between ordering stuff online and bringing stuff home with you is that the thresholds are much higher in the latter case. For example in the UK the threshold is £15 for goods sent by post/courier £390 for most travellers from abroad and £270 for travellers arriving by private board or plane.

Comment: The other difference is if you import the goods yourself you get to decide how honest you will be with customs, if you order online the seller effectively makes that decision.

Comment: lol this question exploded. :P Viewed 2k times in 1 day

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, the CETA free trade agreement applies to **duty/tarifs** not VAT.

VAT is *consumer tax* and when you are the final consumer, you must pay that tax.

---

> [Canada-European Union Comprehensive Economic and Trade Agreement (CETA)](https://www.fedex.com/en-ca/shipping-services/international/regulatory/ceta.html)
> **Important**
>
> **Taxes**. **CETA applies to *duties*, but not taxes**; therefore, any applicable GST/HST for imports into Canada, **and any applicable VAT for exports to the EU**, will be assessed accordingly. For VAT rates and details, visit the European Commission website.

---

**Sources**:

- [Canada-European Union Comprehensive Economic and Trade Agreement (CETA) | FedEx Canada](https://www.fedex.com/en-ca/shipping-services/international/regulatory/ceta.html)

Comment: You normally wouldn't have to pay Canadian GST (/HST) since the goods are exported from Canada.

Answer (score 1):

- GST/HST/PST should never be charged on goods being exported from Canada (the vendor would get an input tax credit).
- Depending on the goods, Duty/Tariff/Excise may be applicable upon import to the EU (this is regulated by CETA).
- VAT (which is the EU equivalent of Canadian GST/HST) would be payable by the buyer upon import to the EU.